# Applying Operation to Pandas column if other column meets criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I'm relatively new to Python and **totally** new to Pandas, so my apologies if this is really simple. I have a dataframe, and I want to operate over all elements in a particular column, but only if a different column with the same index meets a certain criteria.

```
   float_col  int_col str_col
0        0.1        1       a
1        0.2        2       b
2        0.2        6    None
3       10.1        8       c
4        NaN       -1       a
```

For example, if the value in float_col is greater than 5, I want to multiply the value in in_col (in the same row) by 2. I'm guessing I'm supposed to use one of the `map` `apply` or `applymap` functions, but I'm not sure which, or how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be more elegant ways to do this, but once you understand how to use things like `loc` to get at a particular subset of your dataset, you can do it like this:

```
df.loc[df['float_col'] > 5, 'int_col'] = df.loc[df['float_col'] > 5, 'int_col'] * 2
```

You can also do it a bit more succinctly like this, since `pandas` is smart enough to match up the results based on the index of your dataframe and only use the relevant data from the `df['int_col'] * 2` expression:

```
df.loc[df['float_col'] > 5, 'int_col'] = df['int_col'] * 2
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't familiar with the loc function. I was sure there had to be an easy way to get just the subset I wanted, but didn't know how.